# Jest Angular Mock document.head getting Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

We are migrating from karma/jasmine to jest in angular app. We have a common lib in which there is a service which has below property set

```
 export class WrapperService {
    public static readonly BASE_PATH: string = 
    document.head.querySelector("base").getAttribute("href").replace(/\/+$/, "");
    ....
    }
```

Now i have a setup-jest.ts file at root in which i am trying to set the document header like below

```
const documentHTML = '<!doctype html><html><head><base href="/bod-microsite-ui/sso" /></head> 
<body><div id="root"></div></body></html>';
const { document } = new JSDOM(documentHTML).window;
global.document = document;
```

When i run the tests for the lib, i am getting below error wherever this service is injected

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

I have tried various other things but nothing seems to work out. Can anyone suggest any other options or any link to documentation which can guide on how to mock the document for jest ?

Comment: You need to make sure your `global.document = document;` initialization happens before your import of `WrapperService`. Try extracting related to document initialization to separated ts file and import it at the top

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up Jest the following way? (see https://medium.com/@zeeshankhan8838/unit-testing-angular-with-jest-configuration-e324ec61620c)

In short:

1. install jest

```js
npm install --save-dev @types/jest jest jest-preset-angular
```

2. setup.jest.ts

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

3. update tsconfig files (see article)
4. add jest config to package.json (quote from article)

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setup.jest.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/dist/"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$"
      }
    }
  }
```

If you did indeed do all this, then I would recommend the following approach:
Consider refactoring your WrapperService to use `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document` in your WrapperService. You could then mock the document since I don't think you would want to test the functionalities of the document itself. (example):

```js
export class WrapperService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  // Using a getter for BASE_PATH
  get basePath(): string {
    const baseElement = this.document.head.querySelector("base");
    return baseElement ? baseElement.getAttribute("href").replace(/\/+$/, "") : '';
  }
}

// simple mockDocument for in your test
const mockDocument = { 
      head: {
        querySelector: jest.fn()
      }
    } as unknown as Document;
```